# Django Postgresql syncdb error

Tags: python, django, localhost

When I run python manage.py syncdb, I get this error:

```
OperationalError: could not translate host name "localhost" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

my settings.py file looks like this:

```
if "IS_STAGING" in os.environ or "IS_PRODUCTION" in os.environ:
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {'default':dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'test',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
            'USER': 'test',
            'PASSWORD': 'test',
            'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is localhost defined in your /etc/hosts?

Comment: What does 'nslookup localhost' return in your machine?

Comment: you try just putting in 127.0.0.1 or leaving that line blank?

Comment: glasslion, localhost is defined in my etc/hosts.txt file as: 127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: nslookup localhost' returns:

Server:  128.32.136.9
Address: 128.32.136.9#53

** server can't find localhost: NXDOMAIN

Comment: UPDATE!  When i change my settings.py file in my django project to '127.0.0.1' from localhost, i can sync to to the database

Comment: I think the answer is right the in the documentation comment, it explicitly says to leave blank or put '127.0.0.1' if you want to use localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error multiple times. If you're trying to connect to a local database, your best bet is to leave the host as an empty string:

`'HOST': ''`

If that doesn't work, the following should:

`'HOST': '127.0.0.1'`